# filter files in zip command depending on filename

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to zip files and have specified to include only *.pdf and *.xml to be included to the zip file, see below.

```
 $SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Include "*.pdf" , "*.xml"| Select-Object -First $quantity |  Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -lt (Get-date).AddMinutes($time)}
```

My pdf files have a name standard like aaa_bb_cc_123456789.pdf and the xml only have 123456789.xml.

The xmls contain metadata related to the pdf so now I would like to crisp things even more and only zip xml and pdf's that has a matching string in filename (since the complete filename will not be matching).

I have no idea how to solve this so any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Are they always paired 1-to-1? Or might there be multiple PDF's with the same number?

Comment: It cannot be 2 pdfs with the same number. I just want to make sure that the xml file has arrived to the folder before the zip script runs and if not, both the zip and xml should wait until next run.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
# discover all XML files
$filesToZip = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Filter *.xml |ForEach-Object {
  # find corresponding PDF file
  $pdf = Get-Item "*_$([WildcardPattern]::Escape($_.BaseName)).pdf"
  if ($pdf) {
    # we found a valid XML-PDF pair - output both
    $_, $pdf
  }
  else {
    # PDF if missing, warn the caller
    Write-Warning "Found XML file '$($_.Name)' with no corresponding PDF"
  }
}
```

`$filesToZip` will now contain a list of all XML and PDF files for witch a match of the other file type was found

Comment: I have tried to use the above example but cant make it work. I'm writing pdf and xml to a log to see if the code recognize them and get the fllowing lines in my logfile:

[21-11-2023 10:31:08] pdf: .BaseName
[21-11-2023 10:31:08] xml: D:\out\s\test\40002497241201.xml.BaseName
[21-11-2023 10:31:08] pdf: .BaseName
[21-11-2023 10:31:08] xml: D:\ISIS\out\s\PPI\out\40130846211501.xml.BaseName

pdfs located in the folder are named 20230211_1256_4_40002497241201.PDF and 20230211_1256_20_40130846211501.PDF so I must be doing something wrong since they are not found by the script.

Comment: my code:

$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Include *.xml |ForEach-Object {
       
        
         
        # find corresponding PDF file
        $pdf = Get-Item "*_$([WildcardPattern]::Escape($_.BaseName)).PDF"
                
        #write-log -LogOutput ("xml: $pdf.FullName") -Path $LogFile
        write-log -LogOutput ("pdf: $pdf.BaseName") -Path $LogFile
        write-log -LogOutput ("xml: $_.BaseName") -Path $LogFile
        
        if ($pdf) {
            # we found a valid XML-PDF pair - output both
            $_, $pdf
         }
   }